# apply Integrate function to a vector

Tags: r, function, vector

I'm a newbie to R programming and I have an assignment to submit so my prob is the following:
I wrote the following function :

and I should be using integrate () function  to calculate phi(x) for all x
of the vector quantiles and store them in a vector named probs.

I started the following and I got blocked

```
Rep <- function (x) {

vector <-integrate (phi, lower = Inf , upper = x)$Value }
```

Not sure if this is the right way to apply the function integrate() to a vector.
Your help is much appreciated

Comment: First tje equation seems wrong. Ie `exp(-×^2/2)/sqrt(2*pi)` you do not have the closing paranthesis in the correct place. Also this is just the normal distribution. Just use `pnorm` to obtain the probabilities

Comment: thanks for your comment, we're not allowed to use pnorm we have to I need to replicate it through brute-force it is the purpose of the exercise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
phi <- function(x)exp(-x^2/2)/sqrt(2 * pi)
quantiles <- seq(from = 0, to = 5.5, by = 0.01) 


fun<-Vectorize(function(x)integrate(phi,-Inf, x)[[1]])

fun(quantiles)
```